# How to get AvailabilityZone given a SubnetId Parameter, or vice versa, in a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I extracted a CloudFormation template from a stack created by cfncluster. I'm trying to simplify and group the parameters so that the mandatory parameters are grouped together and are non-redundant. The default subnet-related parameters include MasterSubnetId, AvailabilityZone, ComputeSubnetId, and ComputeSubnetCidr. The template uses these to calculate several conditions and also to set AvailabilityZone properties on several resources:

```
"CreateComputeSubnetForCompute": {
  "Fn::And": [
    {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Fn::Not": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"UseComputeSubnetForCompute": {
  "Fn::And": [
    {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Fn::Not": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"UseMasterSubnetForCompute": {
  "Fn::And": [
    {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
        },
        "NONE"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

I want to simplify the template to require either MasterSubnetId or AvailabilityZone, but not both. I don't need the option to provide one or the other, it's fine for me to require one or the other. The main problem is I can't figure out how to do that. The various Resources used by the template seem to require both, even though they should be related. I can't use `Fn::GetAtt` like I want because the first argument cannot come from functions, like this:

```
"Fn::GetAtt" : [ { "Ref": "MasterSubnetId" }, "AvailabilityZone" ]
```

Also, I want the compute fleet to always get its own subnet.

Here are the subnet-related parts of the template :

```
{
  ...snip...
  "Parameters": {
    "ComputeSubnetId": {
      "Description": "ID of the Subnet you want to provision the Compute Servers into. Set to NONE to use the same subnet as Master Server.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "NONE"
    },
    "ComputeSubnetCidr": {
      "Description": "CIDR(s) for new backend subnet(s) i.e. 10.0.100.0/24. This is a comma-delimited list and can support multiple CIDR ranges for a multi-AZ cluster. The order and length of this list MUST match the AvailabilityZones parameter. Set to NONE to use the same subnet as Master Server.",
      "Type": "String",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.",
      "AllowedPattern": "(NONE|(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2}))",
      "Default": "NONE"
    },
    "MasterSubnetId": {
      "Description": "ID of the Subnet you want to provision the Master server into",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
    },
    "AvailabilityZone": {
      "Description": "Availability Zone the cluster will launch into. THIS IS REQUIRED",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name"
    },
    "VPCId": {
      "Description": "ID of the VPC you want to provision cluster into. Only used with UseVPCBase=false",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    },
    "UsePublicIps": {
      "Description": "Boolean flag to use public IP's for instances. If false, the VPC must be correctly setup to use NAT for all traffic.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "true",
      "ConstraintDescription": "true/false",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "true",
        "false"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute": {
      "Fn::And": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Fn::Not": [
            {
              "Fn::Equals": [
                {
                  "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
                },
                "NONE"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "UseComputeSubnetForCompute": {
      "Fn::And": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Fn::Not": [
            {
              "Fn::Equals": [
                {
                  "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
                },
                "NONE"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "UseMasterSubnetForCompute": {
      "Fn::And": [
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Fn::Equals": [
            {
              "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
            },
            "NONE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Mappings": {
    "AWSInstanceType2Capabilites": {
      ...snip...
    },
    "AWSRegionOS2AMI": {
      ...snip...
    },
    "OSFeatures": {
      ...snip...
    },
    "CfnClusterVersions": {
      "default": {
        "cfncluster": "cfncluster-1.1.0",
        "cookbook": "cfncluster-cookbook-1.1.0",
        "chef": "12.4.3",
        "ridley": "4.3.2",
        "berkshelf": "4.0.1",
        "ami": "201602192042"
      }
    },
    "AWSRegion2Capabilites": {
        ...snip...
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    ...snip...
    "CfnClusterPolicies": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "cfncluster",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Sid": "EC2",
              "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": [
                "*"
              ]
            },
            ...snip...
          ]
        },
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "RootRole"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Condition": "CreateEC2IAMRole",

    },
    "MasterEIP": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc"
      },
      "Condition": "MasterPublicIp",

    },
    "MasterServer": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "MasterInstanceType"
        },
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [

          ...snip...
        ],
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "KeyName"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Application",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
            }
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "Master"
          }
        ],
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            "NetworkInterfaceId": {
              "Ref": "MasterENI"
            },
            "DeviceIndex": "0"
          }
        ],
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::If": [
            "UseCustomAMI",
            {
              "Ref": "CustomAMI"
            },
            {
              "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "AWSRegionOS2AMI",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                {
                  "Ref": "BaseOS"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "UserData": {
          ...snip...
          }
        }
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "Comment": "cfncluster Master server",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "configSets": {
            "default": [
              "deployConfigFiles",
              "getCookbooks",
              "chefPrepEnv",
              "shellRunPreInstall",
              "chefConfig",
              "shellRunPostInstall",
              "shellForkClusterReadyInstall"
            ]
          },
          "deployConfigFiles": {
            "files": {
              "/tmp/dna.json": {
                "mode": "000644",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root",
                "content": {
                  "cfncluster": {
                    "stack_name": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    },
                    "cfn_preinstall": {
                      "Ref": "PreInstallScript"
                    },
                    "cfn_preinstall_args": {
                      "Ref": "PreInstallArgs"
                    },
                    "cfn_postinstall": {
                      "Ref": "PostInstallScript"
                    },
                    "cfn_postinstall_args": {
                      "Ref": "PostInstallArgs"
                    },
                    "cfn_region": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    "cfn_volume": {
                      "Fn::If": [
                        "UseExistingEBSVolume",
                        {
                          "Ref": "EBSVolumeId"
                        },
                        {
                          "Ref": "SharedVolume"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "cfn_scheduler": {
                      "Ref": "Scheduler"
                    },
                    "cfn_encrypted_ephemeral": {
                      "Ref": "EncryptedEphemeral"
                    },
                    "cfn_ephemeral_dir": {
                      "Ref": "EphemeralDir"
                    },
                    "cfn_shared_dir": {
                      "Ref": "SharedDir"
                    },
                    "cfn_proxy": {
                      "Ref": "ProxyServer"
                    },
                    "cfn_node_type": "MasterServer",
                    "cfn_cluster_user": {
                      "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "OSFeatures",
                        {
                          "Ref": "BaseOS"
                        },
                        "User"
                      ]
                    },
                    "cfn_ddb_table": {
                      "Ref": "DynamoDBTable"
                    },
                    "cfn_sqs_queue": {
                      "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "SQS",
                        "QueueName"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "run_list": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                      "UseCustomRunList",
                      {
                        "Ref": "CustomChefRunList"
                      },
                      {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                          "",
                          [
                            "recipe[cfncluster::",
                            {
                              "Ref": "Scheduler"
                            },
                            "_config]"
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              ...snip...
            },
            "commands": {
              ...snip...
            }
          },
          ...snip...
        },

      },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Count": "1",
          "Timeout": "PT30M"
        }
      }
    },
    "ComputeFleet": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "MaxSize": {
          "Ref": "MaxQueueSize"
        },
        "AvailabilityZones": [
          {
            "Ref": "AvailabilityZone"
          }
        ],
        "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "UseMasterSubnetForCompute",
              {
                "Ref": "MasterSubnetId"
              },
              {
                "Fn::If": [
                  "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute",
                  {
                    "Ref": "ComputeSubnet"
                  },
                  {
                    "Ref": "ComputeSubnetId"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        ...snip...
      },
      "DependsOn": "MasterServer",
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT30M",
          "Count": {
            "Ref": "ComputeWaitConditionCount"
          }
        }
      },

    },
    "ComputeServerLaunchConfig": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "CreateSecurityGroups",
              {
                "Ref": "ComputeSecurityGroup"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "AddAdditionalSG",
              {
                "Ref": "AdditionalSG"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "UseExistingSecurityGroup",
              {
                "Ref": "VPCSecurityGroupId"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        ...snip...
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "Comment": "cfncluster Compute server",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "configSets": {
            "default": [
              "deployConfigFiles",
              "getCookbooks",
              "chefPrepEnv",
              "shellRunPreInstall",
              "chefConfig",
              "shellRunPostInstall",
              "shellForkClusterReadyInstall",
              "signalComputeReady"
            ]
          },
          "deployConfigFiles": {
            "files": {
              "/tmp/dna.json": {
                "mode": "000644",
                "owner": "root",
                "group": "root",
                "content": {
                  "cfncluster": {
                    "stack_name": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                    },
                    "cfn_preinstall": {
                      "Ref": "PreInstallScript"
                    },
                    "cfn_preinstall_args": {
                      "Ref": "PreInstallArgs"
                    },
                    "cfn_postinstall": {
                      "Ref": "PostInstallScript"
                    },
                    "cfn_postinstall_args": {
                      "Ref": "PostInstallArgs"
                    },
                    "cfn_region": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    "cfn_scheduler": {
                      "Ref": "Scheduler"
                    },
                    "cfn_encrypted_ephemeral": {
                      "Ref": "EncryptedEphemeral"
                    },
                    "cfn_ephemeral_dir": {
                      "Ref": "EphemeralDir"
                    },
                    "cfn_shared_dir": {
                      "Ref": "SharedDir"
                    },
                    "cfn_proxy": {
                      "Ref": "ProxyServer"
                    },
                    "cfn_sqs_queue": {
                      "Ref": "SQS"
                    },
                    "cfn_master": {
                      "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "MasterServer",
                        "PrivateDnsName"
                      ]
                    },
                    "cfn_node_type": "ComputeFleet",
                    "cfn_cluster_user": {
                      "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "OSFeatures",
                        {
                          "Ref": "BaseOS"
                        },
                        "User"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "run_list": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                      "UseCustomRunList",
                      {
                        "Ref": "CustomChefRunList"
                      },
                      {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                          "",
                          [
                            "recipe[cfncluster::",
                            {
                              "Ref": "Scheduler"
                            },
                            "_config]"
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              ...snip...
            },
            "commands": {
              ...snip...
            }
          },
          ...snip...

      }
    },
    ...snip...
    "ComputeSubnet": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnetCidr"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Network",
            "Value": "ComputeSubnet"
          }
        ],
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Ref": "AvailabilityZone"
        }
      },
      "Condition": "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute",

    },
    "ComputeRouteTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Application",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
            }
          },
          {
            "Key": "Network",
            "Value": "ComputeSubnet"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Condition": "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute",

    },
    "ComputeRoute": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeRouteTable"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "NetworkInterfaceId": {
          "Ref": "MasterENI"
        }
      },
      "Condition": "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute",

    },
    "ComputeSubnetRouteTableAssociation": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeSubnet"
        },
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeRouteTable"
        }
      },
      "Condition": "CreateComputeSubnetForCompute",

    },
    "MasterSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable access to the Master host",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "AccessFrom"
            }
          },
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "80",
            "ToPort": "80",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "AccessFrom"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Condition": "CreateSecurityGroups",

    },
    "MasterSecurityGroupIngress": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "-1",
        "FromPort": "0",
        "ToPort": "65535",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeSecurityGroup"
        },
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "MasterSecurityGroup"
        }
      },
      "Condition": "CreateSecurityGroups",

    },
    "ComputeSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Allow access to resources in subnets behind front",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
              "Ref": "MasterSecurityGroup"
            },
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "FromPort": "0",
            "ToPort": "65535"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Condition": "CreateSecurityGroups",

    },
    "ComputeSecurityGroupIngress": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "IpProtocol": "-1",
        "FromPort": "0",
        "ToPort": "65535",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeSecurityGroup"
        },
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "ComputeSecurityGroup"
        }
      },
      "Condition": "CreateSecurityGroups"
    },
    "MasterENI": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "cfncluster Master Server",
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref" : "MasterSubnetId"
        },
        "SourceDestCheck": "false",
        "GroupSet": [
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "CreateSecurityGroups",
              {
                "Ref": "MasterSecurityGroup"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "AddAdditionalSG",
              {
                "Ref": "AdditionalSG"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::If": [
              "UseExistingSecurityGroup",
              {
                "Ref": "VPCSecurityGroupId"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

    },
    "SharedVolume": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Ref": "AvailabilityZone"
        },
        "VolumeType": {
          "Ref": "VolumeType"
        },
        "Size": {
          "Fn::If": [
            "UseEBSSnapshot",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
            },
            {
              "Ref": "VolumeSize"
            }
          ]
        },
        ...snip...

    },
    ...snip...
  },
  ...snip...
```

Comment: What resources are requiring both an AZ and a subnet? Usually, only one or the other is required.